# GIT repository layout for a Solution with multiple projects

Tags: git, github

I was a TFS User where we had a single Solution with multiple Projects and one developer can check out his project when they need. Also the Build system can do separate build for each Project or entire solution at once.

The Project structures include “App” (Mobile App), “Web API”, “Client” etc. There may or may not have dependency on each other

```
\main
   \Development
    \Main
        \App
           \iOS
           \Android
        \JavaAPI
        \WebClient
```

Now I am new to git and want to explore a bit of best practice before committing to a new team. I think git stores everything in a single .git folder at the root of the project tree. So may be we need to either:

1. Set up a separate repository for each Project.
2. Set up a single massive Repository and store Projects in sub folders.

PS: We will be using Jenkins for our CI purpose here.
Are there any guidelines or best practices that I can follow for repositories?

Comment: See also [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Comment: Thank you @gnat for the pointer. I have seen that post, but not able to decide if I should go for Single repo or multiple. I think single repo will be more manageable for us as the code base in not large.